# How do i get a property from a selected ListBox Control 's listboxitem ? C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, listboxitem

like the title said i want to get the value of a property from a selected listboxitem on a button click

```
 <ListBox x:Name="IconListbox" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="Black">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBoxItem x:Name="defaultIcon">
            <Grid Background="Black">
                <Border BorderBrush="#FF1EF3F3" BorderThickness="2">
                    <Image x:Name="defaultIconImage" Width="50" Height="50" Source="icon.png"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Grid Background="Black">
                <Border BorderBrush="#FF1EF3F3" BorderThickness="2">
                    <Image x:Name="secondIconImage" Width="50" Height="50" Source="SecondIcon.png"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

For example if i click the button it should return the image source of the current selected item. So if ListboxItem defaultIcon is selected it should return defaulticon.png.  How can i do this ?

Edit:

Maybe i am taking the wrong aproach by trying to use a listbox. I'm verry new to Xaml code and i'll try to better explain what i want as a result.

Here is a picture that i will use to try and explain: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xYrF.png)

So what i want is when 1 is selected i need it to return the source of the blue flame image when i click the save button

when 2 is selected i need it to return the source of the blue facebook image when i click the save button

Comment: Looks like you forgot to share the code.

Comment: I think the code is there ? i only can show you the Xaml code since i don't know how to get the vallues from the listbox on button press the button does nothing ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the Image inside SelectedItem like the code below

```
        var selectedItem = IconListbox.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
        if (selectedItem != null)
        {
            var image = selectedItem.GetChildOfType<Image>();
            if (image != null)
            {
                var source = image.Source;
            }
        }
```

extension method to get child of specific type

```
     public static T GetChildOfType<T>(this DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            if (depObj == null) return null;

            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

                var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
                if (result != null) return result;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks alot ! Sorry for being a complete newby to these things , but do i put the Extention method under the public partial class mainwindow : Window ?

Comment: @RubenVersavel create a new static class then put the  Extention method inside

Answer (score 0):

IconListbox.SelectedItem and then cast it or create a new object of them.

Example

`Image i = (Image)IconListbox.SelectedItem;`

Comment: i just tried this , it gives me the following error : System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.Image'.'

this is the code i used in the button :
`private void CurrentUserTabSaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Image test = (Image)IconListbox.SelectedItem;

        }`

Comment: what you need to do? i need more info